# Jsch - ssh connection through ssh tunnel

Tags: jsch

I need to connect to a machine with ssh while going tunneling through another machine via ssh - is this possible with Jsch? I've looked at their examples for HTTP tunneling and I'm pretty sure it's not what I'm looking for.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: use jsch shell channel, its possible handle byte stream form remote machine.